# How to observe Ktor download progress by a Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor, ktor-client

I want to observe the download progress by a Flow,
so I wrote a function like this:

```
suspend fun downloadFile(file: File, url: String): Flow<Int>{
        val client = HttpClient(Android)
        return flow{
            val httpResponse: HttpResponse = client.get(url) {
                onDownload { bytesSentTotal, contentLength ->
                    val progress = (bytesSentTotal * 100f / contentLength).roundToInt()
                    emit(progress)
                }
            }
            val responseBody: ByteArray = httpResponse.receive()
            file.writeBytes(responseBody)
        }
}
```

but the `onDownload` will be called only once, and the file will not be downloaded. If I remove the  `emit(progress)` it will work.

`io.ktor:ktor-client-android:1.6.7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `callbackFlow` instead of `flow`. A regular flow can't launch background code, and can only emit values from code inside the flow itself. Meanwhile, a callback flow can launch other work in the background, and then receive callbacks from it.