# Download file with Ktor and show progress with Flow/CallbackFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I was creating a method to download files using `Ktor` using the following logic:

Sealed class to trace the steps

```kotlin
sealed class DownloadType {
    object Started : DownloadType()

    class Progress(
        val value: String
    ) : DownloadType()

    class Finished(
        val file: File
    ) : DownloadType()

    class Failed(
        val throwable: Throwable
    ) : DownloadType()
}
```

`Hilt` Module for `Ktor`

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object KtorModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpClient(): HttpClient = HttpClient(Android)
}
```

Interface to facilitate future maintenance

```kotlin
interface DownloadFileUseCase {
    suspend operator fun invoke(
        url: String,
        name: String
    ): Flow<DownloadType>
}
```

`Ktor` implementation class (with flow)

```kotlin
class DownloadFileUseCaseImplFlow @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val httpClient: HttpClient
) : DownloadFileUseCase {
    override suspend fun invoke(
        url: String,
        name: String
    ): Flow<DownloadType> = flow {
        emit(DownloadType.Started)

        val path = File("${context.filesDir}/example")
        if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs()

        val bytesChannel = httpClient.get(url) {
            onDownload { bytesSentTotal, contentLength ->
                // problem here
                emit(DownloadType.Progress(value = "$bytesSentTotal of $contentLength"))
            }
        }.bodyAsChannel()

        val file = File(path, name)
        bytesChannel.copyAndClose(file.writeChannel())

        emit(DownloadType.Finished(file = file))
    }.catch { error ->
        error.printStackTrace()
        emit(DownloadType.Failed(throwable = error))
    }
}
```

This code only works if we don't use an `emit` inside `onDownload`.

Researching this problem I found another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70782608/19315252), where it was suggested to use the `callbackFlow` instead of the `flow`. The problem is that the answer only had the theoretical part, without the example, so I created a new implementation following luck, because until then I had never used a `callbackFlow`.

`Ktor` implementation class (with callback flow)

```kotlin
class DownloadFileUseCaseImplCallbackFlow @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val httpClient: HttpClient
) : DownloadFileUseCase {
    override suspend fun invoke(
        url: String,
        name: String
    ): Flow<DownloadType> = callbackFlow {
        send(DownloadType.Started)

        val path = File("${context.filesDir}/example")
        if (!path.exists()) path.mkdirs()

        val bytesChannel = httpClient.get(url) {
            onDownload { bytesSentTotal, contentLength ->
                // big difference between these two lines of code (examples attached below)
                // case 1:
                // send(DownloadType.Progress(value = "$bytesSentTotal - $contentLength"))
                // case 2:
                // send(DownloadType.Progress(value = "Downloading file size $contentLength, please wait..."))
            }
        }.bodyAsChannel()

        val file = File(path, name)
        bytesChannel.copyAndClose(file.writeChannel())

        send(DownloadType.Finished(file = file))

        close()
    }.catch { error ->
        error.printStackTrace()
        emit(DownloadType.Failed(throwable = error))
    }
}
```

Now I came across the following situation: if `send` is used for all `bytesSentTotal` on `onDownload`, the process is much longer, if only one `send` is used, the process is faster.

[image: case 1][image: case 2]

With this comparison above, it seems that a `send` is only sent when the last `send` has already been collected, hence the difference in time, as the `bytesSentTotal` is emitted many times...

**Note**:
Both examples were made with the same file;
I collected the `flow` with `collectLatest` in `ViewModel`.

Comment: You can just call the `close` method instead of `awaitClose` to close a flow's channel. What do you mean by showing a long value normally?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman thanks for the feedback, the `close()` method worked. About this other case, I updated the post with more information to be clearer.

Comment: Could you please try to specify a bigger capacity for a channel by using the `buffer` method https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/buffer.html?